# Recover lost files in notepadqq

Tags: files, data-recovery, notepadqq

When I rebooted my laptop, notepadqq asked me if I wanted to recover files. Knowing that I had already saved some of the files in previous session, I clicked on no because otherwise I have observed notepadqq to open bunch of clone windows. Then for some reason notepadqq did not open the latest saved version of those files that I did not chose to recover. It plainly deleted those  files and they are nowhere to be found. Please help me locate those files. Are there cached or hidden versions of such files anywhere on ubunutu fs?

Note: I'd installed notepadqq via snap. 
Also any good alternatives to notepadqq are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was in need to find the answer to this question myself today. Google search landed me to this question. Thought to add answer to this question for other askubuntu users who may land here again in future.

Understood from [this notepadqq issue](https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq/issues/418) that the default directory is `~/.config/Notepadqq/tabCache` on linux. However snap installed version maintain their own config. With snap version of notepaddqq, the files are located in `~/snap/notepadqq/current/.config/Notepadqq/tabCache` folder.